# Transform data while keeping the mean constant

Tags: regression, data-transformation, least-squares

I am using an OLS regression to fit a model to some data. The estimated response is given by the usual

$$\mathbf{\hat{y}} = \mathbf{Py} = \mathbf{X}(\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X})^{-1}\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{y}$$

If the design matrix $\mathbf{X}$ contains a column of $1s$ for the intercept term, then each row (and each column) of the projection matrix $\mathbf{P}$ sums to $1$. This means that the mean of $\mathbf{\hat{y}}$ is equal to the true mean of $\mathbf{y}$, i.e.

$$\mathbf{1}^T\mathbf{\hat{y}} = \mathbf{1}^T\mathbf{Py} = \mathbf{1}^T\mathbf{y}$$

The issue I face is that $\mathbf{\hat{y}}$ may have some values falling outside some allowed region (say, negative values), so I would like to apply a transformation to $\mathbf{\hat{y}}$ such that the mean is maintained but the values are all positive.

Comment: When you face this issue, you should seriously contemplate using a different model.  If you "transform" $\hat y,$ then you risk losing every property of OLS for which it might have been indicated: it will not longer be unbiased among linear estimators; the p-values will be wrong; and you cannot interpret the coefficients in the standard way.

Comment: @whuber Thank you for taking time to read my post and your comment. Unfortunately, I often face constraints imposed externally (such as the use of OLS in this case) which cannot be overcome so easily and I have to come up with (at times "crude") "fixes". This is one of them.

Comment: If you can  do weighted least squares (and re-calculate weights based on the fit to re-fit) then you could replicate (for example) GLMs and nonlinear least squares using linear least squares and so end up using more suitable models in spite of the restriction.

Comment: @Glen_b Thank you for your comment. OLS is all I have to work with at the moment, but I would be interested in exploring your suggestions further. As far as I know, iteratively reweighted least squares is used when the errors are heteroscedastic, but I might be confusing it. Would you be able to point me to a resource / example of applying the technique? Thank you

Comment: 1. You can do weighted LS using unweighted LS. 2. IRLS is used for much more than just heteroskedastic errors.See, for example, slide 14 [here](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~bm508/teaching/AppStats/Lecture5.pdf) which shows how to set up the equations in the case of GLMs. Full details are in many places (I think including the classic McCullagh & Nelder book n GLMs but I don't have it to hand right now).

Comment: @Glen_b Looking at some resources, such as this entry on [Wikipedia]( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteratively_reweighted_least_squares), I see that weights are given as $w_i(t) = |y_i-X_i\beta(t)|^{p-2}$ which for $p=2$ norm means that the weights are always kept at 1, so it doesn't seem to change anything. I must be missing something.

Comment: The main thing missing is the fact that WIkipedia isn't always an ideal reference. That article is written by someone coming from a particular point of view (looks to me like a non-statistician using it in one particular framework), someone ignorant of the very wide variety of applications of reweighted least squares. Indeed the intro to that article 7 years ago at least pointed at the broader landscape - some ass has removed all the pre-exiting parts that give any clue to its broader utility. I already pointed to something that shows how the reweighted least squares updates work in GLMs.

Comment: @Glen_b It seems that in order to use IRLS to find parameters that maximise log-likelihood in GLMs one has to use canonical parameter $\theta$ so that the log-likelihood can be expressed as a product containing $(y_i - \mu_i)$. Is that correct? What if I want to use different parameterisation? Can I still use IRLS to find the solution? In particular, what if I want to use the shape parameters $\alpha$ of gamma distribution as the varying parameters that depends on $\mathbf{X}$?

Comment: Correction to my comment above: the term $(y_i - \mu_i)$ is in the derivative of the log-likelihood w.r.t. $\beta$ (the parameters to be estimated), not in the log-likelihood itself.

Comment: When the shape parameter $\alpha$ of the gamma distribution is used as a dependent variable, I find that $\frac{\partial l_i}{\partial \beta_j}  = (\ln(\nu y_i) - \psi(\nu \mu_i)) \nu \frac{\partial \mu_i}{\partial \eta_i} x_{ij}$ and $E[\frac{\partial ^2 l_i}{\partial \beta_j \partial \beta_k}] = -\psi_1(\nu \mu_i) (\nu \frac{\partial \mu_i}{\partial \eta_i})^2 x_{ij} x_{ik}$ where \nu is the second "rate" parameter of the gamma distribution, and $\psi$ and $\psi_1$ are the digamma and trigamma functions. This doesn't seem to be "expressable" as a product of a weights matrix and design matrix

Answer (score 2):

Let $Y_i^n$ be new $\hat Y_i$ value after transformation.

$$Y_i^n = \frac {\hat Y_i-\bar {\hat Y}}{\bar {\hat Y}- \min(\hat Y_1,...,\hat Y_n)}\bar{\hat Y} + \bar {\hat Y}$$

Then $Y_i^n \ge 0$ and $\bar Y^n = \bar {\hat Y}$ under the condition that $\bar {\hat Y} > 0$. Of course, if $\bar{\hat Y} \le 0 $, there is no solution.

Comment: What connection does your "$\bar Y$" have with the $\hat y$ of the question?

Comment: modified to reflect $\hat Y$.

Comment: Okay, thank you.  It makes one wonder what the resulting value would accomplish.  How would it be interpreted? What would be the properties of this estimator?  It's obviously at risk of being an extremely poor predictor!